# Download a list of file taken from an array url

Tags: vb.net, download

I have a problem with my code . took an array of strings representing the names of some files , I would download them one by one adding to my progress bar . when I run the code files are downloaded but the GUI is not updated within the label , nor the bar is loaded . only when the program exits the loop runs the code outside . updating the interface with the +4 to the bar. How can I update the bar with an increase of 6 after each download of the file ? where am I wrong ? updating while downloading freezes interface

```
Private Sub patchButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles patchButton.Click
    Dim fileDownload(15) As String
    fileDownload(0) = "icon.eix"
    fileDownload(1) = "icon.epk"
    fileDownload(2) = "locale_tr.epk"
    fileDownload(3) = "locale_tr.eix"
    fileDownload(4) = "Metin2_patch_ZodiakMaps.eix"
    fileDownload(5) = "Metin2_patch_ZodiakMaps.epk"
    fileDownload(6) = "metin2_patch_ZodiakMonster.eix"
    fileDownload(7) = "metin2_patch_ZodiakMonster.epk"
    fileDownload(8) = "metin2_patch_ZodiarkArmor.eix"
    fileDownload(9) = "metin2_patch_ZodiarkArmor.epk"
    fileDownload(10) = "metin2_patch_ZodiarkEffect.eix"
    fileDownload(11) = "metin2_patch_ZodiarkEffect.epk"
    fileDownload(12) = "metin2_patch_ZodiarkWeapon.eix"
    fileDownload(13) = "metin2_patch_ZodiarkWeapon.epk"
    fileDownload(14) = "root.eix"
    fileDownload(15) = "root.epk"

    For Each item As String In fileDownload
        consoleLabel.Text = "Update " + item + "..."
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(currentPath + "\pack\" + item) Then
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(currentPath + "\pack\" + item)
            My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(urlResource + item, currentPath + "\pack\" + item)
            ProgressBar1.Value = +6
            If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(currentPath + "\pack\" + item) Then
                consoleLabel.Text = item + "Aggiornato Correttamente"
                ProgressBar1.Value = +6
            End If
        Else
            My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(urlResource + item, currentPath + "\pack\" + item)
            consoleLabel.Text = item + "Update Success"
            ProgressBar1.Value = +6
        End If
    Next
    ProgressBar1.Value = +4
    consoleLabel.Text = "The Client is Update"
    consoleLabel.ForeColor = Color.Green
    patchButton.Enabled = False
    startClient.Enabled = True
    startClient.BackColor = Color.Orange
    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(currentPath + "\" + versionFile)
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(currentPath + "\" + versionFile, versionServer, False)
    versionLabel.Text = "Version: " + My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(currentPath + "\" + versionFile)
    Me.Update()
End Sub
```

Comment: you can use Application.DoEvents() or BackgroundWorker control to complete process and update the user interface. in order to use BackgroundWorker you should at least learn a bit about MultiThreading. [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx) is info about Application.DoEvents() and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx) is info about BackgroundWorker.

Comment: But, in the background worker need insert the download operation or the update user interface operations?

Comment: yes. You will need to use your Network.DownloadFile command and change ProgressBar's Value in BackgroundWorker's DoWork() event and also you will need to update user interface using Invoke () method.